# Match mistyped human names - Postgresql/Python

Tags: python, postgresql

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/91a68/7

Lets say I have a table as follows:

```
create table names(
  f_name varchar(255),
  l_name varchar(255),
  some_value varchar(10)
);

insert into names
values ('HAROLD', 'BUCKBERGER', '10'),
('DERICK', 'WILLIAMS', '1'),
('DOUG', 'LASKOWS', '15'),
('JOE', 'TAYLOR', '12');
```

I get an incremental update next month as follows:

```
create table new_pull(
  f_name varchar(255),
  l_name varchar(255),
  some_value varchar(10)
);

insert into new_pull
values ('HARALD', 'BUCHBERGER', '1'),
('DERRICK', 'WILLIAM', '11'),
('DOUGLAS', 'LASKOWSKI', '12'),
('JON', 'TAYLOR', '13');
```

It is known that the data in the updates is not clean and has mistyped names.
My goal is to match the names between the 2 tables and update `some_value` in the first table with the latest one if it exists. Ignore any new rows for now.

So the ideal final table output should look like this:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║first_name          ║last_name           ║some_value   ║  
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════╣             
║HAROLD              ║BUCKBERGER          ║1            ║
║DERICK              ║WILLIAMS            ║11           ║
║DOUG                ║LASKOWS             ║12           ║
║JOE                 ║TAYLOR              ║12           ║  
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

One idea I had was to use `levenshtein`

```
select n.f_name, n.l_name, np.some_value
from names n
inner join new_pull np
on levenshtein(n.f_name, np.f_name) < 3
and levenshtein(n.l_name, np.l_name) < 3;
```

This generates the following output:
[image]

You can see that it erroneously joins `JOE` with `JON` although both are different names. Changing the threshold would again miss some rows or join some wrong rows.

Is there any reliable matching algorithm which I can use in postgres to get the results I want?
I am open to using any python package as well if its more accurate.

The example I produced here is minimal. There are very annoying typos present in the original data. Happy to clear out confusions if there are any.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: For a good/perfect matching logic you'll need to define a "synonym table". This table will decide which mistyped names correspond to which good ones. The Levenshtein distance can only help you so much.

Comment: Based on what rule/logic are we to declare that Joe and Jon are different people, but Laskows and Laskowski are not?  Especially when the first name is also different.  That is a lot of "typos" to ignore.  You seem to be asking for clairvoyance more then anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with the simlarity function, like:

```
select n.f_name, np.f_name, n.l_name, np.l_name, np.some_value
from names n
inner join new_pull np
on (similarity(n.f_name, np.f_name)>0.4
and similarity(n.l_name, np.l_name)>0.4)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/91a68/12
the docs
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html